# is it wrong to add folder like *folder in .gitignore file?

Tags: android-studio, gitignore

I have 3 flavours in android studio.
when I create any flavour apk then release folder with apk(+somefile) generated under respected flavour folder and this considers as an unversioned file for git.
because
I don't want in git so I added *release in .gitignore file
is it the wrong way to do?
will it create problem in future?

```
myApp
    - .gradle
    - .idea
    - build
    - app
        - build
        - flavour1
            -release
                -app-flavour1-release.apk
                -output-metadata.json
        - flavour2
            -release
                -app-flavour2-release.apk
                -output-metadata.json
        - libs
        - src
            - flavour1
                - somefile
            - flavour2
                - somefile
            - main
            - test
            - androidTest
            - .gigignore
            - build.gradle
            - proguard-rules.pro
            - releasekeystore.jks
        - .gigignore
        - build.gradle
    - openCVLibrary3410
        - build
        - src
        - .gigignore
        - lint.xml
    - scanlibrary
        - build
        - src
        - .gigignore
        - build.gradle
    - .gigignore
    - build.gradle
    - somefile..
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't say it is wrong, but I would recommend you make sure the pattern in the gitignore file fits with your standard project layout as strictly as possible to avoid the case where someone makes a folder later and it is unexpectedly ignored.

`\*release` will ignore any file or folder ending in "release" within the same folder as the ignore file. In my projects I often hyphenate special folders like that such as "linux-release" so I would probably use"*-release" in that case to reduce the cases it would match as much as possible.

All this to say that what you have done shouldn't cause any problems but I would go the extra mile to make sure it is not unpredictable to the rest of your team by being more specific in the pattern now.

If you'd like, post a better example of your folder structure to offer more direct advice.

**Example of a Different Practice:**
In many projects i have worked on we put releases in `build/release/android` and `build/release/ios` folders. We have `build/` in our .gitignore and use these subfolders of build specifically because every dev knows anything in that folder should be the result of a build or byproducts of it, which are not version conrtolled. So our devs know any folder named build, even in another non-src directory is not something probably shouldnt be used for storing files in git.

Comment: what is better practice for the same? Thank you

Comment: Hi @Yash. I added an example of what we do, but of course you should do what is best for your team. We just try to set a standard with our project structure to prevent odd mistakes later in any project. I hope this helps and good luck to you!

Comment: HI @Anonymike. I already added /build in .gitignore it was working before I added flavour after adding flavour, release folder generate in app/flavour/release. that is why...

Comment: I see...then, you could either modify the gradle config to move your release folders, or do something like `app/*/release` to get only the release folders inside a subfolder of app. It's a little bit more specific than `*/release` and should have less chance of conflicts with meaningful folders.

Comment: Hi @Yash, could you please add edit the question to add an example of your project structure? Then I may be able to give you an example that works for your project.

Comment: hi, @Anonymike I have an updated question.